# Retrieve data from external static JSON file and use in AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am looking to pull some data from an external static JSON file based on an event sent to AWS Lambda.

So when someone sends their "customer_id" we pull the matching "email" and "option" from the external JSON file

https://3objects.netlify.com/3objects.json

Here is the code I have so far?

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ses = new AWS.SES();
const request = require('request');

exports.handler = (event) => {
    console.log(event.customer_id);

    request({
url: 'https://3objects.netlify.com/3objects.json',
method: 'GET',
headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
body: JSON.stringify({
})
}, function (error, response) {
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(body); // turn response into JSON

    // do stuff with the response and pass it back to Lambda...
});



    // After JSON data retrieval of 'email' and 'option' from https://3objects.netlify.com/3objects.json we send them an email with this info
    clientEmail = email;
    contact_option = option;

    var eParams = {Destination: {ToAddresses: [clientEmail]}, Message: {Body: { Text: { Data: 'Your contact option is ${contact_option}' },},Subject: { Data: "Your Contact Preference" }}, Source: "sales@example.com"};
    var email = ses.sendEmail(eParams, function (err, data) { if (err) console.log(err); else { console.log("===EMAIL SENT==="); } });
};
```

How can I query and use that external JSON url data?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to using [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch). It is a package that let you use the `fetch` function from ES6.

I created an example of using node-fetch. The function `getCustomers` gets the customers from the url.

Then I created a function that returns a `Promise`. Inside this Promise, the retrieved data is send by mail using `AWS.SES()`.

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
ses = new AWS.SES(),
fetch = require('node-fetch');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  console.log(event.customer_id);
  
  const customers = await getCustomers();
  
  customers.map(async customer => {
    await sendEmailToCustomer(customer);
  });
}

async function getCustomers() {
  try {
    const resp = await fetch('https://3objects.netlify.com/3objects.json');
    const json = await resp.json();
    
    console.log(json);
    return json;
  }
  catch(e) {
    throw e;
  }
}

const sendEmailToCustomer = (customer) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  ses.sendEmail({
    Destination:
      { ToAddresses: [customer.email] },
    Message:
      {
        Body: { Text: { Data: `Your contact option is ${customer.customer_id}` }},
        Subject: { Data: "Your Contact Preference" }
      },
    Source: "sales@example.com"}, (error, result => {
      if (error) return reject(error);
      resolve(result);
      console.log(result);
    })
}
```

Comment: This is looking good, just getting an error with the "map" part when I try and run it  ```Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"```

Comment: @Gracie woops, I forgot to return the fetched data :)

Answer (score -1):

In general, you should post the exact error you're facing instead of general question.  it would help contributors to figure out the problem you're facing.

In your code snippet above, the part

```
    // After JSON data retrieval of 'email' and 'option' from https://3objects.netlify.com/3objects.json we send them an email with this info
    clientEmail = email;
    contact_option = option;

    var eParams = {Destination: {ToAddresses: [clientEmail]}, Message: {Body: { Text: { Data: 'Your contact option is ${contact_option}' },},Subject: { Data: "Your Contact Preference" }}, Source: "sales@example.com"};
    var email = ses.sendEmail(eParams, function (err, data) { if (err) console.log(err); else { console.log("===EMAIL SENT==="); } });
```

is executed before the `request` returns.  You need to move that code inside your callback to execute it when the `request` finishes.

I also would suggest you to convert your code to `async`/`await` for better readability and avoid this type of error.
See this article to learn how to do that : https://www.stormacq.com/2019/06/22/async-js.html